# ListView and FlipView combined in xaml

Tags: objectlistview

I'm trying to combine two components(ListView and FlipView) in an windows store app , but I have a problem when click on the flipview next button becouse I want to listview just scroll items and don't select them.
How can i do that?
I find some examples and modify them and now this is the only problem that I have.
Thx.

Here is my code:

```
<Page
x:Class="FlipViewPreviewIndicator.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:FlipViewPreviewIndicator"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FlipViewStyle" TargetType="FlipView">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel AreScrollSnapPointsRegular="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlipView">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="3">
                            <Border.Resources>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalNextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M4.12,0 L9.67,5.47 L4.12,10.94 L0,10.88 L5.56,5.47 L0,0.06 z" Fill="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="10.94" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9.67"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalPreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M5.55,0 L9.67,0.06 L4.12,5.47 L9.67,10.88 L5.55,10.94 L0,5.48 z" Fill="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="10.94" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9.67"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalNextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M0.06,0 L5.47,5.56 L10.88,0 L10.94,4.12 L5.48,9.67 L0,4.12 z" Fill="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="9.67" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10.94"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalPreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M5.63,0 L11.11,5.55 L11.05,9.67 L5.64,4.12 L0.23,9.67 L0.17,5.55 z" Fill="{StaticResource FlipViewButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="9.67" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10.94"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Border.Resources>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="209"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollingHost" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" VerticalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                    <ScrollViewer.ContentTransitions>
                                        <TransitionCollection>
                                            <RepositionThemeTransition/>
                                        </TransitionCollection>
                                    </ScrollViewer.ContentTransitions>
                                    <ItemsPresenter Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                                <Button x:Name="PreviousButtonHorizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalPreviousTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="70"/>
                                <Button x:Name="NextButtonHorizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalNextTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="70"/>
                                <Button x:Name="PreviousButtonVertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource VerticalPreviousTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70"/>
                                <Button x:Name="NextButtonVertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource VerticalNextTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="70"/>
                                <ListView 
                                            ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"  
                                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" 
                                            Padding="0,0,0,40" 
                                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                                            SelectionChanged="ListViewSelectionChanged1" Margin="75,0">
                                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid/>

    <FlipView Grid.Row="1" d:DataContext="{Binding Source={d:DesignInstance Type=local:SampleData, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"  ItemsSource="{Binding SampleItems}"  Style="{StaticResource FlipViewStyle}"  >

    </FlipView>

</Grid>
```